# Max OS X: White saturation is terrible

Tags: macos, mac, mac-mini

I bought a new LCD-Monitor: Acer S235HLBbmii.
I had Windows 8 until today. The colors with Windows (and this monitor) were very good. All tests on this website are very good:
http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/

I connected my new Apple Mac Mini (2012, quadcore 2.3 GHz) to this display. The colors are very terrible.

I tried macOS color calibration, different modes/settings in the OSD menu and the Windows 7 Color Profile (ICM) from the Acer website.

This test especially is just worst: http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/white.php

It shows me the first block (200). I can't see any other. So you can imagine that bright pictures with a lot of white amount looks very bad.

Switching back to Windows 8 isn't considerable so I need to get this fixed.

Here is a link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pf667jgx2idz4sl/Foto%2005.02.13%2020%2012%2043.jpg

P.S.: I downloaded and installed all updates. Monitor is connected via HDMI 1.4 Cable (good quality) and also i tried the old DVI to HDMI-Cable (which powered the display under windows) with the adapter that was shipped. Not a single improvment.

P.S.S.: Tested video out on my 27 inch Yamakasi, the white saturation is near the same. It's crap. It's oviously a software fault. What can i do to fix this? :-(

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried calibrating the colors yourself from the Displays preference pane?  Mac OS X's default gamma is indeed different than other OSes.  Try turning on the Expert mode for additional control.

Comment: Check for YPbPr TV mode instead of RGB mode if HDMI cables or connections are potentially in play - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/61447/5472

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I FIXED IT!
The HDMI out of the mac mini is very poor. I connected the via mini displayport and all went fine.

(mini displayport -> dvi -> hdmi, crazy but works better then HDMI <> HDMI).

Comment: Check for YPbPr TV mode instead of RGB mode if HDMI cables or connections are potentially in play - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/61447/5472

Answer (score 0):

You may have the same problem that drove me crazy today.

[Check out this article](http://embdev.net/topic/284710), I smell the same issue.

Also, [the other relevant thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56555/dell-u2410-hdmi-os-x-lion-very-poor-quality/81120#81120) where I posted the same answer.